# xlwings chart simulator - Unable to duplicate Macro Sheet with Simulation Chart

Tags: python, excel, vba, charts, xlwings

1. I downloaded sheet with Simulation chart from xlwings, along with the .py Python script that excel calls to run simulation.
2. Duplicated the sheet on Excel workbook.
3. Saved additional .py script and relinked all reference to the duplicated sheet.
4. Created new function on Alt+F11 with a new name to call on the duplicated .py script.
5. Checked for referencing errors, all intact except that the duplicated excel tab could not run simulation for the chart due to error line within .py script:

**sht.charts['Chart 5'].set_source_data(sht.range((1, 15), (num_timesteps + 2, 19)))**

Specifically, it seems to highlight the problem on **'Chart 5'**. I dont know a workaround for this without making big changes to the code. Full error description below:

---

### Error

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in

File "GBM_2.py", line 26, in main
    sht.charts['Chart 5'].set_source_data(sht.range((1, 15), (num_timesteps + 2, 19)))

File "C:\Users\Darius\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 78, in **getitem**
    return self(key)

File "C:\Users\Darius\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 49, in **call**
    return self._wrap(impl=self.impl(name_or_index))

File "C:\Users\Darius\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\xlwings_xlwindows.py", line 1122, in **call**
    raise KeyError(key)

KeyError: 'Chart 5'

***Actual .py script:***

```
from __future__ import division
import sys
import numpy as np
import xlwings as xw


def main():
    sht = xw.Book.caller().sheets('GBM2')
    # User Inputs
    num_simulations = sht.range('E3').options(numbers=int).value
    time = sht.range('E4').value
    num_timesteps = sht.range('E5').options(numbers=int).value
    dt = time/num_timesteps  # Length of time period
    sig = sht.range('E7').value
    mu = np.log(1 + sht.range('E6').value)  # Drift
    starting_price = sht.range('E8').value
    perc_selection = [1, 50, 99]  # percentiles (hardcoded for now)
    # Animation
    animate = sht.range('E9').value.lower() == 'yes'

    # On Excel: clear output, write out initial values of percentiles/sample path and set chart source
    # and x-axis values
    sht.range('O2').expand().clear_contents()
    sht.range('P2').value = [starting_price, starting_price, starting_price, starting_price]
    sht.charts['Chart 5'].set_source_data(sht.range((1, 15), (num_timesteps + 2, 19)))

    sht.range('O2').value = np.round(np.linspace(0, time, num_timesteps + 1).reshape(-1, 1), 2)

    # Preallocation
    price = np.zeros((num_timesteps + 1, num_simulations))
    percentiles = np.zeros((num_timesteps + 1, 3))

    # Set initial values
    price[0,:] = starting_price
    percentiles[0,:] = starting_price

    # Simulation at each time step
    for t in range(1, num_timesteps + 1):
        rand_nums = np.random.randn(num_simulations)
        price[t,:] = price[t-1,:] * np.exp((mu - 0.5 * sig**2) * dt + sig * rand_nums * np.sqrt(dt))
        percentiles[t, :] = np.percentile(price[t, :], perc_selection)
        if animate:
            sht.range((t+2, 16)).value = percentiles[t, :]
            sht.range((t+2, 19)).value = price[t, 0]  # Sample path
            if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
                sht.book.app.screen_updating = True

    if not animate:
        sht.range('P2').value = percentiles
        sht.range('S2').value = price[:, :1]  # Sample path
```